# CSS3 Width Transition Messing Design Up

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I want to achive a transition effect as soon as an user hovers over one of the
icons on the navbar. The text which just gets displayed at the moment should
have a width transition. I tried to do this by myself but I couldn't get it done
without destroying the rest of the design

HTML:

```
<header>
  <img src="http://www.websignature.ch/img/logo_nav.png" alt="WebSignature"/>
</header>

<nav>    
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cogs"></i><span>Services</span></a></li><!--
 --><li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-th-list"></i><span>Projects</span></a></li><!--
 --><li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-users"></i><span>About</span></a></li><!--
 --><li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i><span>Contact</span></a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0.5em;
  height: 4em;
  width: 100%;
  background: #2196F3;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #2196F3, #1976D2);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(right, #2196F3, #1976D2);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, #2196F3, #1976D2);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #2196F3, #1976D2);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}

header img {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #2196F3;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #2196F3, #1976D2);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(right, #2196F3, #1976D2);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, #2196F3, #1976D2);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #2196F3, #1976D2);
  -webkit-filter:drop-shadow(2px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.75));
}

nav:before {
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  right:100%;
  width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 81.78px solid #2196F3;
    border-left: 81.78px solid transparent;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0.7em;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 2em;
}

nav ul li a span {
  display: none;
  padding-left: 0.5em;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

nav ul li a:hover span {
  display: inline;
}
```

JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/Yunnigg/gL1uLLjs/

Comment: You cannot animate the span tag because it's set to "display: none" You can try using visibility hidden and perhaps negative text indent. I'll mess around in a few for you.

Comment: i know that it's not possible with "display: none;" but everytime i try to make a width transition the whole nav gets messed up. Thx

Comment: I added an answer for you below. Check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a shot. Basically, what I'm doing here is animating text-indent on the span element. This will point you in the right direction.

```
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0.5em;
  height: 4em;
  width: 100%;
  background: #2196F3;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #2196F3, #1976D2);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(right, #2196F3, #1976D2);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, #2196F3, #1976D2);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #2196F3, #1976D2);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}

header img {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #2196F3;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #2196F3, #1976D2);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(right, #2196F3, #1976D2);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(right, #2196F3, #1976D2);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #2196F3, #1976D2);
  -webkit-filter:drop-shadow(2px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.75));
}

nav:before {
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  right:100%;
  width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 81.78px solid #2196F3;
    border-left: 81.78px solid transparent;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

nav ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0.7em;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 2em;
}

nav ul li a span {
  padding-left: 0.5em;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  text-indent: -160px;
  transition: all 200ms;
}

nav ul li a:hover span {
  text-indent: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much it worked wonderfully. I just had to add a "vertical-align: middle;" to the text and the icon.

Comment: No problem, you'll need to adjust your CSS because it's not 100% perfect. Please select this as the answer if you don't mind :)

Comment: i know that i need to adjust some things. I'm just messing around and trying to create a good looking navigation. Any recommended changes to the CSS?

Comment: Yes, I know you are using the html comment code to eliminate the small gaps with display inline-block. I'd remove that and simply add negative margin or lets say -3px to each LI element. Other then that, it does what you are looking to do. Checkout below, he has provided another solution that is good as well.

Answer (score 1):

Here is working **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m_tanzi/gL1uLLjs/3/)**

Hope it helps. :)

**Thanks**

Modefied `nav` css

```
nav ul{
 -webkit-transition:all 0.3s ease;
 transition:all 0.3s ease;
}
nav ul li {
 display: inline-block;
 -webkit-transition:all 0.3s ease;
 transition:all 0.3s ease;
}

nav ul li a {
 display: block;
 width:50px;
 padding: 0.7em;
 color: #ffffff;
 text-decoration: none;
 white-space:nowrap;
 font-size: 2em;
-webkit-transition:all 0.3s ease;
 transition:all 0.3s ease;
 position:relative;
}

nav ul li a span {
 display: none;
 padding-left: 0.5em;
 overflow: hidden;
 font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
 }
nav ul li a:hover span{
display:inline;
}
nav ul li a:hover {
width:250px;
}
```

Comment: Thx for the fiddle, but i like Derek Bess' solution a little bit better, because in yours, you can see the text behind the icons during the transition, which i don't that appealing. Anyway thanks :)